# Any PHP or MySQL function to get the Unix time without affecting the Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, unix, datetime

I have stored a time in my *database*, for example this data: `2014-03-25 13:15:00`

But when I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_field)` through *mysql query* or `strtotime()` in ***PHP***, both functions output is effected by timezone.

Please tell me if it's possible to get *unix time* without timezone effect?
It will also be very helpful if anyone can provide a *PHP function*.

Please do not suggest to me to change the timezone, because this is not a suitable solution.

Current output of `2014-03-25 14:05:00` when covert to unix and then again convert to date `2014-03-25 08:35:00`

**UPDATE**

this not only happen only to DB time. like if I directly call this : 
`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(2014-03-25 14:05:00))`

then it output

```
2014-03-25 08:35:00
```

Comment: What timezone are your servers set to?

Comment: what data type you used to store the time?

Comment: I never set timezone, i think it will be default timezone. (by the way I am using WAMP)

Comment: @hago I use timestamp data type, but this problem is related to timezone

Comment: Perhaps it is not the solution, but this may help you..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374089/timezone-differences-between-php-and-mysql?rq=1

Comment: @briosheje I tried most of solutions on stackoverflow, but most of them says same method. This is the main problem that I cannot ask my script user to change settings of their server :-(

Comment: @user007 : Okay, so let's try to understand exactly what you want to do... can we find a logic behind this? what is actually the difference between the UNIX_TIMESTAMP and the strtotime? is it proportional in your case?

Comment: Thanks. UNIX_TIMESTAMP and the strtotime output are same, but they are being effected by timezone, I am getting 2 hours back time.

Comment: Performing `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_type_column)` will not perform any timezone conversion whatsoever, as `TIMESTAMP` type columns are already stored in UTC.  However, storing literal `'2014-03-25 13:15:00'` into a `TIMESTAMP` type column **must** therefore convert from the session's [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) to UTC, which is presumably the effect to which your question refers.  But how could one expect otherwise?

Comment: @user007 the most possible cause is that you set up different timezone while inserting and selecting, I think.

Comment: this not only happen only to DB time. like if if directly call this : `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(2014-03-25 14:05:00))` then it output `2014-03-25 08:35:00`.

Comment: Yes mine time is India Standard Time (IST) = GMT+5:30. But I am curious that how other script managed to out put correct time they do not ask to change setting. what solution they are using ? I tried to look in their code but they are using almost same I am doing.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime):

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-03-25 13:15:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2014-03-25 13:15:00
echo $date->format('U'); // 1395753300
```

This assumes the times in your database are expressed in UTC.

#### Before PHP 5.3

```
$date = '2014-03-25 13:15:00';
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date GMT"));
```

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the literal is in fact in UTC (which I somehow doubt).  :)

Comment: Thanks I will try this solution, but most of my users are not uing php5.3 (i know its old) but then I have to ask them to update to 5.3. But indeed I will try this.

Comment: @user007 I've added pre 5.3 version.

Comment: Your solution output correct date when I use gmdate() but still UNIX time is not correct. I have already time stamp, and I want correct UNIX time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `strtotime('2014-03-25 14:05:00')` is outputting `1395756300 `

Comment: @user007 First you only had a date and now you have a timestamp? What exactly do you want?

Comment: @user007: In what timezone is your literal?  If it's UTC, then `1395756300` is correct.

Comment: I have set my timezone to UTC in PHP, all is fine now. Thanks @eggyal